# Angular2 How to protect content

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I want to implement some very simple login trying to apply good OOP conceptos however I can not share vars between Components.

Basic I have a main component that have two child componentes Login and ProtectedComponent, the flow is when a person is Logged I want hide login component and show protected component. You Can see the code Below.

```html
import {bootstrap, Component, View, NgIf} from 'angular2/angular2';

//Protected-Content Component
@Component({
  selector: 'protected-content'
})
@View({
  templateUrl: 'app/views/protected-component.html'
})
class ProtectedComponent{
}


//Login Component
@Component({
  selector: 'login'
})
@View({
  templateUrl: 'app/views/login.html'
})
class Login{
  login(username, password){
    if(username.value =="test" && password.value=="test"){
      isLogged = true;
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'main'
})
@View({
  template:`
  <login *ng-if="!isLogged"></login>
  <protected-content *ng-if="isLogged"></protected-content>`,
  directives:[Login,ProtectedComponent,NgIf]
})
class Main{
  isLogged:boolean;
  constructor(){
    this.isLogged = false;
  }
}

bootstrap(Main);
```

Any Idea?

Comment: I think you can`t protect content on front end. For example console in Chrome can read config from Firebase

Answer (score 0):

I used [EventEmiter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/EventEmitter-class.html) for this purpose, it's allows to communicate between components. Here is good [example](http://schwarty.com/2015/08/14/angular2-eventemitter-and-custom-event-name/) .

Answer (score 0):

Or extend the RouteOutlet class and use instruction.component = Login to route the user to Login component if login failed (can be checked by a static isLogged:boolean in the extended class).

https://auth0.com/blog/2015/05/14/creating-your-first-real-world-angular-2-app-from-authentication-to-calling-an-api-and-everything-in-between/